# How to convert int to char* using syscall?

Tags: c++, c, operating-system, mmap, system-calls

This is part of an assignment to learn more about syscall.

How can I convert a int in C++ using a syscall instead of using sprintf or any other library functoins in C++ I think I need to use mmap but I can find any documentation on how to use it

Comment: I'm sure you have an interesting reason to want to do this; I'd like to know what it is.

Comment: What is wrong with sprintf?

Comment: nothing its part of an assignment trying to understand how syscalls work but I couldnt find any good information on this

Comment: What should the result of the conversion be? Given the `int` value `42`, do you want a `char*` result that points to a string with the value `"42"`, or are you looking for something else? Which operating system are you using (different systems have different system calls)? And finally, why should there be a syscall for something that can be done easily in user (non-kernel) code?

Comment: I'm just wondering: why do you think that mmap will help you here?

Comment: @KeithThompson You are right it just a simple conversion from int 42 to char* "42", I am using ubuntu, it part of understanding how the operating system works what happens when you use sprints or something similar

Comment: @JohnZwinck Most likely, it's to learn the process of adding a system call, building the code that implements a new system call, writing user-space code that calls a new system call, and debugging it until the whole thing works. It's the first step to learning how to add more complex functionality to the kernel and access it from user space.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that with a syscall.  If the syscall needs a string convert your integer to string before invoking the syscall.  Use sprintf for the conversion.

Comment: Why can't he do it with a syscall? And when you say "the syscall", what syscall are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

1. Implement a system call that converts an `int` to a `char *`, using existing system calls as examples.
2. Boot into the kernel that supports your system call or load the module that implements it.
3. Write demonstration code that invokes that system call.
4. When the kernel crashes, debug your system call.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that by "convert int to char*" you mean generating a character representation of an integer value. So for instance if we have:

```
int i = 379;
char str[256];
```

you are looking for a syscall call that will take i for input and output "379" to str.

Syscalls are architecture dependent. So I need to know what platform/architecture you are targeting here. Syscall allows you to call a 'system service' (that is, a basic routine), and you are probably in luck because most platforms have services to print integers and strings.

So what platform are you working on?

Comment: I am using a unmodified version of ubuntu

Comment: Ubuntu is the OS. What's the architecture ?